# How to INSERT in SQL from nothing with empty rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I have a table that doesn't have any rows.  When I do `select 1 from table` it returns an empty result. How can I force the `select` to contain a single value?

```
INSERT into table2
select 1 from table2   -- table2 is empty here
```

Comment: So you want as many 1's as there are rows, with at least 1 row with the value `1`?

Comment: No, you must now... If you're going to SHOUT at us, and show no effort, I have no further interest helping you; and I am sure others won't either... I really suggest you take the [tour] and learn what [so] is *really* about. It is not a free coding service, and we (the users giving our free time to answer you) are not here to answer your beck and calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want *exactly* one value regardless of the number of rows in the table, you can use aggregation:

```
INSERT into table2
    select max(1) from table2 ;
```

Of course, you could just phrase this as:

```
INSERT into table2
    select 1;
```

Both of these assume that `table2` has only one column, which is rather uncommon.

You might also want to duplicate all rows, and then choose one row.  One method is:

```
insert into table2
    select t2.*
    from (values (1)) v(x) left join
         table2 t2
         on 1=1;
```

This inserts *all* columns into the table.  It always inserts at least one row.  That row would have `NULL` values if there are no rows in `table2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use

```
INSERT into table2
select 1;
```

Comment: To explain the downvote, I downvoted because this answer has already been provided

Comment: I appreciate your thought. You did the right thing. Actually the window was open before the answer and I didn't notice. If it was not upvoted I would have removed this. Best wishes.

Comment: You are most welcome. Best wishes. You will find it as an excellent platform to learn together.

Comment: @squillman thanks a lot. please guide me what should I change in edit.

Comment: Eh, just add a ; to the end of the select if it'll let you

Comment: :) Awesome. Best wishes.